# JSF2 and Spring Webflow (<h:commandLink> doesn't respond inside <ui:repeat> facelet tag)

Tags: jsf, facelets, spring-webflow

i am trying to have a List of commandLink in every cell of dataTable.

this is small example explaining what i am trying to do

```
<h:form id="form1">
<p:dataTable id="doctorTable" var="doctor"
value="#{search.medecinsResult}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
<p:column headerText="#{search.headerDate[1]}">
<ui:repeat var="seance" value="#{search.column2[rowIndex]}">
    <h:commandLink value="#{seance}" action="Reserver"
                        title="Réservez cette séance">
    </h:commandLink>
    <br />
</ui:repeat>
</p:column>
</p:datable>
</h:form>
```

And i define transition on the page viewState in my XML flow:

```
<view-state id="result">
<transition on="Reserver" to="next">
</transition>
</view-state>
```

the commandLink work fine outside repeat tag, but when its inside it just reload the webpage

i found JIRA issues for that, but it not resolved.
[link to JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1269?page=com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin%3acrucible-issuepanel)

if there is any workaround it will be great, thank's for your responses.

Comment: Please pay a bit more attention to the correctness of the code snippets. The `</p:datable>` is obviously wrong and would only end up in a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `<ui:repeat>` which is the culprit. It doesn't work very well when nested in another repeating component. There are many [related issues](http://java.net/jira/secure/QuickSearch.jspa?searchString=ui%3arepeat) for that already, the JSF guys are working on that. The usual solution is to pick a "fullworthy" JSF `UIData` component instead, such as `<h:dataTable>`. Since you're already using PrimeFaces, I'd suggest to try `<p:dataList>` instead.